# LaTeX document class for conference talk notes?

Tags: document-classes

I want to typeset some notes I'm taking at talks within a conference. These are not lecture notes, and are taken online without being filled in later with information from textbooks or interaction other talk attendees. (Although I guess it's not a completely dissimilar kind of document class than for lecture notes.) Has anybody written such a class I could use/play with?

To be more specific about relevant features:

- Ability to properly describe the speaker (incl. affiliation, invited or note, etc.)
- Indication of track / parallel session info
- Differentiation between notes from speakers actual talk, notes from the following Q&A, links section or some other graphically-pleasing way to present links
- Commands for interruption, pause, interchange with audience member, non-verbal actions, unintelligible bit, etc.

Answers such as "use another document class X and adapt in Y-ishly" are also appreciated.

Comment: This is highly specific and i guess everybody would suggest to simply use article and define a few own commands. Maybe writing a wrapper class using article.

Comment: @Johannes_B, that was my first thought, I prefer to keep to routine LaTeX use when using it to take notes. Rather than article and a `\section` per talk you might want to use a class that allows a `\chapter{}` per talk, keeping `section` clear for the major parts of the talk plus discussion, and `subsection` for individual slides or Q&A questions (I would put the question as the subsection heading in case I generate a TOC.  However the OP is asking for something quite specific and at the very least would need a (per-chapter) group of fields for author(s) affiliation, session/talk ID.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Well, it's less specific than per-academic-institute thesis classes... anyway, I thought maybe someone might have created one.

Comment: I do this, but do not have a specific class. I just have a "template" .tex file that has the formatting I like, that I copy for each speaker and include in my main .tex file. Then I fill in the blanks. I have it set up to create indices for speaker, conference, location, topic, etc.